# Just starting Piano and Theory is confusing and interesting to me at the same time. Anyway resources or tips to learn?

Tags: theory

The title is basically what it is. Piano is fascinating to me and I'd like to be able to understand and play it. Theory really gets confusing for me so are there any resources or places where I can learn more theory? Right now I barely can grasp a basic understanding.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Learn to play. Learn notation.   When you've got your fingers round some pieces, then's the time to look into how they're put together!

Answer (score 1):

Music theory is a complicated topic that involves a lot of practice to truly understand. If you have a private teacher, ask them for help with anything you don't understand. And take the time to look for online resources like musictheory.net.

You can also use music theory method books like the Hal Leonard ones, Keith Snell, etc. But overall, I would suggest you play a lot of different pieces and study them carefully. Look at the way the composer modulates, how they use scales and arpeggios and chord progressions.